# Null dereference control in c#

Tags: c#, fortify

After some testing which is about "null dereference", below code can "dereference a null pointer, thereby raising a NullException".

```
if((validateControl as WebControl) != null)
    (validateControl as WebControl).CssClass (IsValid) ? "stack" : "overflow";
```

Can (validateControl as WebControl).CssClass be null with above using?

The result is seen in document which is produced by Fortify.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: is it `validateControl` really? What's `IsValid`?

Comment: isValid is page.IsValid which is bool.

Comment: You question is very unclear, as your code is. If I understand well you would like to do line 1 and line 2 in 1 step ? In that case I don't think this is possible...

Comment: "The result is seen in document which is produced by Fortify" --> I think he is trying to eliminate a static code analysis error - which is probably where the 'Fortify' tool helps

Comment: Not a real question. It's like asking, is `#000000` really black?

Comment: I don't see any pointers.

Comment: @DouglasHeld can you share your intention on [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275309/should-undiscussed-burninates-be-approved-fortify360-in-this-case)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get `false` when it's not a `WebControl`, and `true` otherwise:

```
bool isWebControl = validateControl is WebControl;
```

To get `null` when it's not a `WebControl`, and a `WebControl` otherwise:

```
WebControl webControl = validateControl as WebControl;
```

---

#### Can `(validateControl as WebControl)` be null?

Yes, every time you use `as`, the result *could be* null in theory. Code analysis tools don't see that you just checked that it is not null, and will still assume the next use of `as` is possibly null. So you should put it in a variable and use that instead:

```
WebControl webControl = validateControl as WebControl;
if (webControl != null)
{
    // Here 'webControl' is surely _not_ null.
    webControl.CssClass = Page.IsValid ? "stack" : "overflow";
}
```

---

#### Can `(validateControl as WebControl).CssClass` be null?

The value you get from `CssClass` might be null. But since `CssClass` is a property, the property will always be there as long as `validateControl` is a `WebControl`.

Answer (score 2):

How about reformatting your code to be more explicit.

```
var webControl = validateControl as WebControl;
if(webControl != null)
{
    var cssClass = IsValid ? "stack" : "overflow";
    webControl.CssClass = cssClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could.
If it matters, once you know validateControl is not null and is a WebControl, then you test CssClass for nullability and possibly empty  or just whitespace depending on what "valid" means